# Binding to custom Dependency Property fails

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dependency-properties

As the `SelectedItems property` of the ListBox control is a normal property and **not** a dependency property to bind to, I have derived of the ListBox and created a new dependency property `SelectedItemsEx`.

But my XAML compiler keeps giving me the error

> A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'SelectedItemsEx' property of the
>   type 'MyListBox'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty
>   of a DependencyObject.

Why my property is not recognized as a dependency property? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

XAML:

```
  <MyListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" SelectedItemsEx="{Binding SelectedEx}" 
                                            SelectionMode="Extended"> ... </MyListBox>
```

ListBox' implementation:

```
public class MyListBox : ListBox
{
    public readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsExProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItemsEx", 
                typeof(ObservableCollection<MyItemsDataType>), 
                typeof(MyListBox), 
                new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<MyItemsDataType>)));


    public ObservableCollection<MyItemsDataType> SelectedItemsEx
    {
        get
        {
            var v = GetValue(SelectedItemsExProperty);
            return (ObservableCollection<MyItemsDataType>)v;
        }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemsExProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
        if (SelectedItemsEx != null)
        {
            SelectedItemsEx.Clear();
            foreach (var item in base.SelectedItems)
            {
                SelectedItemsEx.Add((MyItemsDataType)item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DependencyProperty` field must be static:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsExProperty = ...
```

---

Note also that in order to make your derived ListBox a little more reusable, you should not constrain the type of the `SelectedItemsEx` property. Use `IEnumerable` (or `IList` like `SelectedItems`) instead. Moreover, there is no need to specify a default value by property metadata, as it is `null` already and `default(<any reference type>)` is also `null`.

You will however have to get notified whenever the `SelectedItemsEx` property has changed. Therefore you have to register a change callback via property metadata:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsExProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SelectedItemsEx", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(MyListBox),
        new PropertyMetadata(SelectedItemsExPropertyChanged));

public IEnumerable SelectedItemsEx
{
    get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(SelectedItemsExProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedItemsExProperty, value); }
}

private static void SelectedItemsExPropertyChanged(
    DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var listBox = (MyListBox)obj;
    var oldColl = e.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
    var newColl = e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;

    if (oldColl != null)
    {
        oldColl.CollectionChanged -= listBox.SelectedItemsExCollectionChanged;
    }

    if (newColl != null)
    {
        newColl.CollectionChanged += listBox.SelectedItemsExCollectionChanged;
    }
}

private void SelectedItemsExCollectionChanged(
    object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```